# In mirror mode, why is it not balanced with the reference picture

Tags: modeling

When I'm ready to put on mirror mode - Control A - Add Location. The eyes are always not lined up with the reference picture. How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons:

- The reference image is symmetrical but not centered, in this case align the offset of the background image (x,y):

[image]

- The reference image itself isn't symmetrical. This would require to cut one half of the image off and mirror the other half by a image processing tool.